# How to cut a part of a 3D object?

Tags: object, 3d, blender

I am noob with Blender.

I am here because I have some difficulty using the "project knife" tool in edit mode.

I have watched some tutorials about this, but no one helped me.

In "object mode" I select first the mesh model and with Shift+LMB the entire object, when I switch thought the edit mode and I select knife project, but I receive an error: "no other selected object found to use for projection".

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knife Project requires two objects to work: a reference object, and the one you want the part cut out of. So, for example, if you want to cut a circular hole out of a cube, you would do the following:

1. Create the cube mesh object
2. Create a circle mesh object
3. position the circle so that it's aligned with wherever you want the hole to be cut out of (i.e., if you want a hole cut out of the top of the cube, rotate and move the circle to the top of the cube)
4. Select the circle, then shift+LMB select the cube
5. Go to edit mode and click Edit > Knife Project

That's all! You should then be able to see the new vertices of the circle placed onto the cube. You can choose to remove the selected faces in your newly cut out hole, or not.

Are you sure you're selecting two separate mesh objects? That seems to be the error you're getting.